# Does TextMate have an easy way to indent 2 spaces for a HAML file?

Tags: textmate, haml

I look around for the preferences in TextMate and there seems to be no method to set the indent to 2 spaces when we highlight some code and choose

```
Text -> Shift Right
```

Right now it is indenting 4 spaces but is there a way to make it 2?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

It's on the bottom bar off the application towards the middle.
It'll say something like 'Soft Tabs: 4' if you click it you can change it to do 2 spaces for tabs.

Comment: if it is changed to 2, and then "Text -> Shift Right" is used on highlighted text, then a tab is actually inserted for each line... it shows as 2 spaces, but the compiler for HAML will complain that it is tab instead of space.

Comment: you may want to look into using the `expand` command in the terminal for your compiler.

Comment: @ Jian Lin
When you select the the little drop down to set the tab size (it either says `Soft Tabs: 4` or `Tab Size: 4`) ensure that there is a check at the bottom where it says `Soft Tabs (Spaces)` this will use spaces for indentation and tabs.

Comment: Did this fix the issue for you?

Comment: yes i think so... just that at first, when i click "right arrow" there after soft tab is inserted, it moved 2 spaces by 2 spaces, making me thinking that it is not space but was a tab that was inserted... i had to copy and paste that code to another text editor to verify that it was 2 spaces.

Answer (score 2):

Also you can edit multiple lines by holding <kbd>Option</kbd> and dragging your mouse along the spot in the lines. When you type, the text will be on all the lines you selected at that spot.